# Privacy of school accounts

Tags: networking, email, calendar

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu for performance reasons, and I am setting up my email and calendar. I use google calendar and Gmail.

On the "Online Accounts" section, I set up both my personal account, as well as my school account. My school tracks everything I do if I am using a school account, or connected to my school board wifi or school board server. If I add the school account, will they be able to track what is on my PC? My connection to the internet is almost always my personal account (unless I am doing Online School) but will adding my school account to my "Online Accounts" section and using it as part of my email and calendar, allow the board to have access to any other part of my computer?

Comment: As an aside, switching because of performance reasons is valid, but it's not a great reason (by itself).  You should look at the complete set of trade offs.  If you're looking for better privacy (or privacy features you can understand), you may want to give up Google products, but you'll have trade offs there, too.  Same with abstaining from using Amazon for, say, ethical reasons.  All these situations involve trade offs of various kinds.  So, zoom out to the 30K ft. level to see what you're giving up and what you're gaining.

Comment: @jrw32982 My school requires us to use google products, but for all home accouts (aside from google nest mini and the doorbell) everything is apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it won't allow them to see any files on your computer, nor any activity that occurs through the non-school accounts.

Of course, if you mistakenly use the wrong account and put your nefarious and secretive activities into your school e-mail or school account, then they will certainly know. But that is YOU spilling the beans; not Ubuntu.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the school can still track _when_ they are using their computer if emails/calendar are automatically and periodically synchronized.

Comment: @user535733 ok so, when I go to my Files, I can see my google drive as a removable device, does that allow them to see the rest of the files?

Comment: No, of course not. Google cannot see anything about your local files. If random folks could easily rummage through your system, that would be a remarkable security hole.